# Combine similar column values in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have the pandas dataframe as below

```
A        B     C
Apple   20     A1
Apple   30     A2
Apple   40     A3
Kiwi    20     K1
Kiwi    30     K2
Kiwi    10     K3
```

I want the output as

```
A        B     C
Apple   20     A1
        30     A2
        40     A3
Kiwi    20     K1
        30     K2
        10     K3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html):

```
In [938]: df.loc[df.groupby('A').cumcount().ne(0), 'A'] = ''

In [939]: df
Out[939]: 
       A   B   C
0  Apple  20  A1
1         30  A2
2         40  A3
3   Kiwi  20  K1
4         30  K2
5         10  K3
```